# display data only on selecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

i have a check box, and want that when it is selected/checked, values from another file (i.e c_datetime.php) should get loaded, for this i have used ajax, when i select/check the checkbox the values are getting loaded properly but when i uncheck it the loader gets loaded again and the ajax displays the data again, whereas the proper way should have been that when the checkbox is selected the values should get loaded and when its unselected the values should disappear, can anyone please tell why its not working the way it should

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#drive').change(function(){

        var catid = $('#drive').val();
        console.log($('#drive'))
        if(catid != 0)

        {
            LodingAnimate();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'c_datetime.php',
                data:{id:catid},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#datetime').html(returndata);
                console.log(returndata)
                }
            });

             function LodingAnimate() 
                {
                    $("#datetime").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" height="40" width="40"/>');
                } 
        }
    }
    )
}) 

</script>   


<div id="datetime"> </div>
<input type="checkbox" name ="chk" id="drive" value="Drive" >Drive
```

Comment: you should check if the checkbox is check only then load the data add `if($(this).is(':checked')) `condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#drive').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var catid = $('#drive').val();
            console.log($('#drive'))
            if (catid != 0)

            {
                LodingAnimate();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'c_datetime.php',
                    data: {
                        id: catid
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (returndata) {
                        $('#datetime').html(returndata);
                        console.log(returndata)
                    }
                });

                function LodingAnimate() {
                    $("#datetime").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" height="40" width="40"/>');
                }
            }
        }else{
            $("#datetime").hide();
        }
    })
})
```

Try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52mjw76m/1/)

you should check if the checkbox is check only then load the data add `if($(this).is(':checked'))` condition

Comment: it displays data on selecting checkbox but is not hiding the content on unselecting it

Comment: you do it on else part of if condition. I didnt include it you can do it

Answer (score 2):

Try using `if` condition `this.checked` within `change` event handler.
If `#drive` property `checked` returns `true` , call `$.ajax()` , else do not call `$.ajax()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#drive').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      // do `$.ajax()` stuff
      console.log(this.checked)
    } else {
      // do not do `$.ajax()` stuff
      console.log("not checked")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="drive" value="Drive">Drive
```

Comment: i also need to hide data when checkbox in unselected

Comment: @kavi _"i also need to hide data when checkbox in unselected"_ Could place `js` that hides data in `else` statement at stacksnippets . `js` in `else` statement should be called when `input type="checkbox"` `checked` property returns `false` at `this.checked`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are looking for:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
padding: 20px;
display: none;
margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
$(".red").toggle();
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> Drive</label></div>
<div class="red box">
<img src="Koala.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
            // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
            foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
                echo $selected."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You could add a little explanation to your code here.